# bind data from jlist to appear on a jtable

Tags: java, swing, hibernate, jtable, jlist

I'm developing a `JAVA` swing application, developed using `hibernate` and `mysql` as a database.

I'm trying to bind data from a `JList` to appear on a `JTable`, when one of items in the list is clicked. For example i have different user types in my application, Supervisor, Manager, Administrator and others.

Each of the user type has users register under them. I want the application to show certain users when a certain item is clicked on the `JList`. Like when I click on the supervisor item then all registered supervisors must appear on the `JTable`. Don't know if I'm making sense, but you all allowed to reply and I will try to make you understand better. Thanks.

Comment: Please post some of your code. Thanks

Comment: I have used a drag and drop approach rather than writing a source code, i have already binded the user groups on the jlist im struggling to show the data under each group. Im asking of a good way of doing this

Comment: ofcourse it make sense using `jList1ValueChanged` Listener you can get value of corresponding value in jtable.
show your effort first..

Answer (score 1):

> Like when I click on the supervisor item then all registered supervisors must appear on the JTable.

One way is to populate the table with all the data and then filter the table when you select an item from the JList. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Sorting and Filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting).

Otherwise you would need to dynamically query you database every time a JList item is selected.

In either case you will need to add a ListSelectionListener to your JList to invoke your processing. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on `How to Use Lists` for an example.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i have already filtered the table, im now trying to work on events when clicking on a jlist item. Thanks for the help